# Medoo Limit not working

Tags: php, medoo

I have faced an unexpected problem

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    include_once("Medoo.php");
    use Medoo\Medoo;

    $db = new Medoo([
        'database_type' => 'mysql',
        'database_name' => '************',
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '************',
        'password' => '************'
    ]);

    function getThreads($db, $start, $limit){
        $data = $db->select('threads', ['id', 'title', 'content', 'date', 'userid'],  ["AND" => ["active" => "1", "limit" => [$start, $limit]]]);
        return $data;
    }

    function utf8ize($d) {
        if (is_array($d)) {
            foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
                $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
            }
        } 
        else if (is_string ($d)) {
            return utf8_encode($d);
        }
        return $d;
    }

    $start=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['start']));
    $limit=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['limit']));

    $query = getThreads($db, $start, $limit);
    if($query == false) {
        echo json_encode(array("code" => "failed"));
    } 
    else {
        echo json_encode(utf8ize($query));
    }
?>
```

If I call the php file through ajax with parameters start 0 and limit 5, I get always "failed" from console.log(); as result. Already tried debug() function from medoo but the sql query looks good. Without Limit everything works fine...  Any ideas or suggestions? Can somebody help?

```
var start = 0;
var limit = 5;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://*********/****/********.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "text json",
    data: "&start="+start+"&limit="+limit,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.code == "failed"){

        } else {
            start += limit;
            data.reverse();
            $('#threads').html("");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if(data[i]['userid'] == localStorage.id){
                    $('#threads').append("<ons-card onclick='pushpc("+data[i]["id"]+","+data[i]["userid"]+");'><div id='threadid'>"+data[i]["id"]+"</div><div class='title'>"+decode_utf8(data[i]["title"])+"</div><div class='content'>"+decode_utf8(data[i]["content"])+"</div></ons-card>");
                } else {
                $('#threads').append("<ons-card onclick='pushpc("+data[i]["id"]+","+data[i]["userid"]+");'><div id='threadid'>"+data[i]["id"]+"</div><div class='title'>"+decode_utf8(data[i]["title"])+"</div><div class='content'>"+decode_utf8(data[i]["content"])+"</div></ons-card>");
            }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know nothing about Medoo, but the position of the `"limit"` element, in the third parameter to `$db->select()` seems a bit odd to me. Shouldn't it be something like `["AND" => ["active" => "1"], "limit" => [$start, $limit]]`? In other words, the `limit` clause separated from the `where` clause items like `AND`? (Or perhaps it should even be passed in a whole separate parameter to `$db->select()`?)

Comment: `["AND" => ["active" => "1"], "limit" => [$start, $limit]]` returns all database entries and the sql query looks like this: `SELECT "id","title","content","date","userid" FROM "threads" WHERE "active" = '1'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it:

```
  $data = $db->query("SELECT id, title, content, date, userid FROM threads LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit."")->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 5):

it should be

```
   function getThreads($db, $start, $limit){
    $data = $db->select('threads', ['id', 'title', 'content', 'date', 'userid'],  ["active" => "1", "LIMIT" => [$start, $limit]]);
    return $data;
   }
```

LIMIT is not a condition in medoo, you can use it without "AND"